# Case Statement that runs sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am applying a mask to data and believe the best way is to use a `Case` Statement.  However, I need the `case` statement to run a sub query.  When I pull data, it will either be a number or appear as `99999999999v999b:99999999999v999-`

Using

```
TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(RD.subm_quantity, '^(\d+)(-)?$', '\2\1'))/1000 as "Submitted_Quantity"
```

This will convert it to a number. So if 00000000100000 is present, it will convert to 100

However, I need a case to not divide when not needed. To determine if I need to divide, I need to add a rule in the below sql:

- if the result is `99999999999v999b:99999999999v999-`, apply the conversion;
- if not, just output `RD.subm_quantity`.

How can I get a `case` statement to run a query?

Running in TOAD for Oracle:

```
select m.mask 
FROM Valiuser.ivd_mapping             m,
   Valiuser.ivd_mappingset          s,
   Valiuser.ivd_mapping_record      r,
   Valiuser.ivd_transaction_file    tf,
   VALIUSER.ivd_transaction_record_details RD  
WHERE     s.mappingset_id = r.mappingset_id
   AND r.mapping_record_id = m.mapping_record_ID
   AND m.repository_column_id = '34'
   AND s.mappingset_id = tf.MAPPINGSET_ID
   AND rd.file_id = tf.file_id
   AND rd.TRANSACTION_RECORD_ID =
```

Comment: You want the mask linked to the same `rd` record that has the specified `transaction_record_id` from that query, is that right? If so why do you need a subquery - what will that be finding?

Answer (score 1):

If the `mask` and original `subm_quantity` are both available from the query you showed, which *seems* to be the same as that includes the `rd` table you're referencing in the conversion, then I think you want something like this:

```
case when m.mask = '99999999999v999b:99999999999v999-'
     then TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(rd.subm_quantity, '^(\d+)(-)?$', '\2\1')) / 1000
     else rd.subm_quantity
end as "Submitted_Quantity"
```

rather than a subquery. So plugged into your current query that would make it:

```
SELECT
  case when m.mask = '99999999999v999b:99999999999v999-'
       then TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(rd.subm_quantity, '^(\d+)(-)?$', '\2\1')) / 1000
       else rd.subm_quantity
  end as "Submitted_Quantity"
FROM
   Valiuser.ivd_mapping             m,
   Valiuser.ivd_mappingset          s,
   Valiuser.ivd_mapping_record      r,
   Valiuser.ivd_transaction_file    tf,
   Valiuser.ivd_transaction_record_details rd
WHERE
       s.mappingset_id = r.mappingset_id
   AND r.mapping_record_id = m.mapping_record_ID
   AND m.repository_column_id = '34'
   AND s.mappingset_id = tf.mappingset_id
   AND rd.file_id = tf.file_id
   AND rd.Transaction_Record_Id = <?>
```

or with modern join syntax instead of the old version, something like:

```
SELECT
  case when m.mask = '99999999999v999b:99999999999v999-'
       then TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(rd.subm_quantity, '^(\d+)(-)?$', '\2\1')) / 1000
       else rd.subm_quantity
  end as "Submitted_Quantity"
FROM Valiuser.ivd_mapping m
JOIN Valiuser.ivd_mapping_record r ON r.mapping_record_id = m.mapping_record_ID
JOIN Valiuser.ivd_mappingset s ON s.mappingset_id = r.mappingset_id
JOIN Valiuser.ivd_transaction_file tf ON tf.mappingset_id = s.mappingset_id
JOIN Valiuser.ivd_transaction_record_details rd ON rd.file_id = tf.file_id
WHERE m.repository_column_id = '34'
AND rd.transaction_record_id = <?>
```